# NameError within moviepy subclip function

Tags: python, package, nameerror, moviepy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Gamble\main.py", line 159, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Gamble\main.py", line 128, in main
    link = create_clip(count, "WITHDRAW", root)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Gamble\main.py", line 53, in create_clip
    new = video.subclip(int(frame / 60 - 5), int(frame / 60 + 5))
  File "C:\Users\Evan\anaconda3\envs\F\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\anaconda3\envs\F\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 79, in wrapper
    names = inspect.getfullargspec(func).args
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

I haven't altered anything in the package nor could I find anything online about this the code causing this error in question is

```
with VideoFileClip(root) as video:
    new = video.subclip(int(frame / 60 - 5), int(frame / 60 + 5))
    new.write_videofile(f'{root.split(".")[0]}/{claim}{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(frame / 60)))}', audio_codec='aac')
```

Comment: I see other people already sended similar problem on MoviePy's GitHub. [issues](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues)

Comment: I managed to fix it and posted it below

Comment: old version `1.0.3` doesn't have this problem (at least on Linux without Anaconda). The newest code on GitHub also has corrected version but maybe it needs to wait until they create new package which can be installed with `pip`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they accepted a PR that broke the code. I managed to fix it by going into decorators.py and changing any instance of "func" to "f"

Comment: Or uninstall conda-forge version and get the one from pip. It's [fixed upstream](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1789).

Comment: I had similar problem with "conda install -c conda-forge moviepy". Do "conda remove moviepy". Then, "pip install moviepy". The error "name" func not found issue was gone.